Is there a construction of the octonions inside a Clifford algebra?
Octonion multiplication can't be Clifford multiplication since the latter is always associative. Still, given the connections between octonions and spinors and Clifford algebras (see John Baez's notes), there must be a construction of the octonions that uses the structure of a Clifford algebra in a nontrivial way. What is it?

This can be found in Clifford Algebras and Spinors by Pertti Lounesto.

Here is an explicit embedding of the octonions in $\def\|#1{\mathbb{#1}} C\ell_0(\|R^7) \cong M_8(\|R)$.
Let $\def\e{\mathbf e} \{\e_1, \ldots, \e_7\}$ be an orthonormal basis for the pseudovectors. I'll write $\e_{12}$ as a shorthand for $\e_1\e_2$. Depending on sign choices, $\e_{1234567}=\pm1$; choose it to equal the octonion product $e_1(e_2(\cdots(e_6e_7)))))$, which in the multiplication tables I've seen is always $-1$.
Let $\|O_{\mathrm v}$ be the eight-dimensional subspace of the Clifford algebra spanned by $(e_0, e_1, \ldots, e_7) \triangleq (1, \e_1, \ldots, \e_7)$. This is the vector representation of the octonions.
Let $\def\P{\mathrm P} R_\P(x) = x\P$, where $\P$ is a projection of (matrix) rank 1. For example you can take $\P = \frac18(1+\e_{1357})(1+\e_{2367})(1+\e_{4567})$, which yields the multiplication rule used by Graves and Cayley, in which $e_ae_b = \pm e_{a\oplus b}$ (where $\oplus$ is bitwise xor), or $\P = \frac18(1+\e_{3567})(1+\e_{4671})(1+\e_{5712})$, which yields the cyclic table used by John Baez and many others. (Note that the quadvectors in these projections, considered as vectors over $\|Z_2^7$, generate the dual of the (7,4) Hamming code.)
Let $\|O_{\mathrm s} = R_\P(\|O_{\mathrm v}) = R_\P(C\ell_0(\|R^7))$. This is the spinor representation of the octonions.
Restricted to $\|O_{\mathrm v} \to \|O_{\mathrm s}$, $R_\P$ is a bijection. Its inverse, for these choices of $\P$, is $R_\P^{-1}(y) = 8\left( {\langle y\rangle}_0 + {\langle y\rangle}_6 \right)$ where ${\langle\cdot\rangle}_k$ is Clifford-rank projection.
Octonion multiplication as a function $\|O_{\mathrm v}\times\|O_{\mathrm s}\to\|O_{\mathrm s}$ is Clifford multiplication. If the arguments aren't of the correct representation type, you have to insert $R_\P$ or $R_\P^{-1}$ to convert them; this is where the nonassociativity comes in.
Of course there is a conjugate embedding with $\|O_{\mathrm{s'}} = L_\P(\|O_{\mathrm v})$ and Clifford multiplication taking $\|O_{\mathrm {s'}}\times\|O_{\mathrm v}\to\|O_{\mathrm{s'}}$.
The same construction in $\|R^{4,3}$ yields the split octonions. You can use the same $\P$ if you order the metric signature so that the quadvectors in the projection still square to $+1$.
A similar construction in $\|R^{9,1}$ yields 2×2 octonionic matrices, which are mentioned in Baez's notes, §3.3 as related to $\mathrm{Spin}(9,1)$. However, it appears that the construction of the spin group from these matrices erases the octonionic structure and gives you the same Clifford-algebraic embedding that exists in any dimension.
The 8-dimensional ternary cross product is related: it can be calculated in $C\ell(\|R^8)$ as $A\times B\times C = 16\langle ABC\P' \rangle_1$, where $\P' = \P(1\pm ω)/2$, $\P$ is a projection like those above, and $ω$ is the 8-dimensional pseudoscalar. The 4- and 8-vectors in $\P'$, considered as vectors over $\|Z_2^8$, generate the dual of the (8,4) extended Hamming code.
There is also an interesting embedding of the octonions in $C\ell(\|R^{3,3})$. Let $\{\e_1, \ldots, \e_6\}$ be an orthonormal vector basis with signature ${++}{-+}{--}$, and let $\P = \frac18(1+\e_{16})(1+\e_{25})(1+\e_{43})$. This can be understood as a projection onto the light cone: the factors are "rescaled infinite Lorentz boosts", $\lim_{α\to\infty} \exp(α\,\e_{ij})/e^α = \frac12 (1 + \e_{ij})$. The equivalent of $\|O_{\mathrm v}$ represents $e_i$ as a multivector by a sort of binary code. Unfortunately it can't be as simple as $\e_1,\e_2,\e_{12},\e_4,\e_{14},\ldots$, because $e_4$ couldn't anticommute with all of $e_1,e_2,e_3$. Instead, the following works, and gives the Graves/Cayley table: $e_0 = 1$, $(e_1,e_2,e_4) = (\e_{24},\e_{14},\e_{12}) \e_{356}$, $(e_3,e_5,e_6) = \e_{124} (\e_3,\e_5,\e_6)$, and $e_7 = -\e_{124}$. There may be a more elegant way to do it.
